# Find when the particular line created or updated in file

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to find when a particular line has created or updated in the file. Currently the time is not logging along with lines and lines are appending in single file for each day.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String line0 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).get(0);
    System.out.println(line0);
}
```

Here I want at what time line0 has added or updated.

Comment: Add a time to the beginning or end of the line when it's logged to the file. Usually operating systems only keep track of when files are modified, accessed and/or created.

Comment: File is creating by third party and we have no access to change that.

Comment: Then you're SOL. Asking an operating system to keep track of times associated with every new line in every file would require so much overhead.

Comment: Use a real database instead of reinventing your own.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes BalusC, need a different approach ... Thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

Monitor the file change using WatchService, then manually diff all the lines with a copy that you will unfortunately have to store in memory